# Need help to fix Exception

Tags: windows-phone-7, exception, app-hub

Can someone explain the following 2 crash exceptions! I am unable to understand how do I fix them -

Frame    Image             Function                                                                Offset
0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                                                      19
1        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                            436488
2        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                            386545
3        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                            540936
4                          TransitionStub                                                          0
5                          MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult                                     100
6                          MS.Internal.XcpImports.MessageBox_ShowCore                              112
7                          System.Windows.MessageBox.ShowCore                                      272
8                          PhotoRotator.TransformedImage.SaveButton_Click                          504
9                          Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarItemContainer.FireEventHandler      292
10                         Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButton.ClickEvent               88
11                         Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButtonContainer.ClickEvent      60
12                         Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar.OnCommand                          160
13                         Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.NativeCallbackInteropWrapper.OnCommand    72
14       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                            429164
15       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                            430528
16       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                            610803
17       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                            393257
18                                                                                                 0
19       corex.dll         ApplicationBarInterop::ApplicationBarCallback::OnCommand                15

the specific piece of code is presented as below -

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(SelectedImage.TransformedImage);
            MemoryStream targetStream = new MemoryStream();  

            wb.SaveJpeg(targetStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

            if (targetStream != null)
            {
                targetStream.Seek(0, 0); // necessary to initiate the stream correctly before save

                try
                {
                    MediaLibrary ml = new MediaLibrary();
                    Picture p = ml.SavePicture(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), targetStream);
                    MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully to your Media Library!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error - " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unexpected error!");
            }
        }
```

2nd one ->

Frame    Image             Function                                                                        Offset
0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                                                              19
1        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                    436488
2        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                    386545
3        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                    540936
4                          TransitionStub                                                                  0
5                          Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Helpers.ThrowExceptionFromErrorCode                     80
6                          Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary.GetPictureFromToken                  280
7                          PhotoRotator.MainPage.OnNavigatedTo                                             216
8                          Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedTo             288
9                          System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.RaiseNavigated                      488
10                         System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CompleteNavigation                  812
11                         System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback    968
12                         System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread        1108
13                         ._*c*_DisplayClass4._BeginLoad_b__0                                             64
14       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                    429164
15       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                    185803
16       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                    184423
17                         System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke                              112
18                         System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke                              1560
19                         System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke                                             104

The piece of code for this is ->

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
            {
                // Get a dictionary of query string keys and values.
                IDictionary<string, string> queryStrings = this.NavigationContext.QueryString;

                // Ensure that there is at least one key in the query string, and check whether the "token" key is present.
                if (queryStrings.ContainsKey("token"))
                {
                    // Retrieve the picture from the media library using the token passed to the application.
                    MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
                    Picture picture = library.GetPictureFromToken(queryStrings["token"]);

                    // Create a WriteableBitmap object and add it to the Image control Source property.
                    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
                    bitmap.SetSource(picture.GetImage());

                    //WriteableBitmap picLibraryImage = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
                    //retrievePic.Source = picLibraryImage;

                    SelectedImage.OriginalImage = bitmap;

                    navigateCompleted(null, null);
                    //NavigationService.Navigate(HelperClass.Constants.TransformPageUri);
                    //NavigationService.Navigated -= new NavigatedEventHandler(navigateCompleted);
                }
            }
```

Comment: SHowing some of the code that's causing them would be a good start.

Comment: I have added the code for your reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please add some code, but the first exception looks like there is a error in the click event of the save button:

```
8 PhotoRotator.TransformedImage.SaveButton_Click 504
```

try to debug it step by step. and give us some code

Comment: I have done debiugging, but it seems its must be failing at some special condition. I have added the code for your reference.